# SQL Anywhere 12 Problem with sentence CREATE DOMAIN

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

This produce an syntax `ERROR:-131.`

```
CREATE DOMAIN dom CHAR(35);
```

Anyone knows why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE DOMAIN "dom" CHAR(35);
```

Perhaps dom is a keyword. Or - more probably - there already exists something named **`dom`**. Did you run the command twice?

If yes, the first time you run it, it created the domain "dom". The second time, it's typical to "answer" that you **can't create another domain with the same name**, using the obvious error code of **`-131`** .